# How to resolve rquery project_se error in count distinct summarization?

Tags: r, rquery

I'm new to rquery and assume I'm doing something obviously wrong. When I attempt to use the function project_se and a count distinct argument the function fails due to an unexpected symbol:

```
df_main <- df %.>%
    rquery::project_se(.,
                       groupby = qc(cust, trans_date), 
                       c("sales" %:=% "sum(sales)",
                       "gross_profit" %:=% "sum(gross_profit)")) %.>%
   rquery::project_se(.,
                      groupby = qc(cust),
                      "trans_count" %:=% "count(distinct trans_date)")
```

> Error in parse(text = ai) : :1:16: unexpected symbol 1:
>   count(distinct trans_date

However the following works fine:

```
    df_main <- df %.>%
    rquery::project_se(.,
                       groupby = qc(cust, trans_date), 
                       c("sales" %:=% "sum(sales)",
                       "gross_profit" %:=% "sum(gross_profit)")) %.>%
   rquery::project_se(.,
                      groupby = qc(cust),
                      "trans_count" %:=% "count(trans_date)")
```

Given the `parse(text = ai)` error I'm guessing R is trying to convert that into R code rather than just pass the sql statement? What is confusing to me is that other sql functions work just fine such as `str_to_date`.

Comment: try `count(distinct(trans_date))`

Comment: That seems to work, but I'm curious about how this is being executed in the background as something more idiomatic like: "max_date - INTERVAL '1' YEAR" likely won't fit that mold.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question. But so far only little can be found about rquery on SO. So some input might be helpful for beginners.

An alternative solution to `count(distinct(trans_date))` is to use `sql_node()`.

```
df %.>%
  sql_node(., "trans_count" %:=% "count(distinct trans_date)", 
           mods = 'group by cust',
           orig_columns = F) %.>%
  execute(db,.)
```

`sql_node()` also accepts other Postgres-Syntax such as `max_date - INTERVAL '1' YEAR`.